# Proving that the potential solution to a differential equation converges (or not)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I'm looking at this equation:

$$x''(t) - \sin(x(t))\cdot x'(t) + a ^{2}x(t) = 0$$

My question is therefore / how to prove that a solution is not convergent. [Numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27(t)%20-%20sin(f(t))%20*%20f%27(t)%20%2B%2010%20f(t)%20%20%3D%200) we can see it oscillates but I'm not sure how to prove it.

So far I've proven it stays at a bounded distance to the solution of:

$$x''(t) + a^2x(t) = 0$$

(Gronwall lemma)

Comment: The constant solution $0$ converges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the differential equation is invariant under the transformation $x \to -x$, $t \to c -t$.  Thus a solution that starts at $x(0) = 0$, $x'(0) = v_0$ and goes to $x(t_1) = 0$, $x'(t_1) = v_1$ will come back to $x(2 t_1) = 0$, $x'(2 t_1) = v_0$ on the other side of the $x'$ axis, and continue in a 
closed orbit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I didn't think about this point of view. However, the fact that $x$ passes at $0$ twice seems necessary to me for your argument to work with a general initialization. Though it seems obvious from your figure, do you have a simple proof for this ?

Comment: The equilibrium point $(0,0)$ is a centre for the linear approximation, so either a centre or a stable or unstable spiral in the nonlinear system.  In each of these cases,
a trajectory that starts sufficiently near the origin on the positive $x$ axis will hit the negative $x$ axis.